# Javascript Compare UTC time to Local time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to prevent orders from being placed after 9am EST. If someone places an order from another timezone, I need to check the server time, not the local time. The problem is that the Server time zone is UTC but the script is using the local timezone.

```
// Same shipping up till 9am
var shipTime = 0;
var currentTime = new Date();
if (currentTime.getHours() >=9){
    shipTime = 1;
}  

$( ".add_delivery_date").datepicker( {
    minDate: shipTime,  
    firstDay: 0,
    beforeShowDay: setHolidays
});
```

**EDIT**

This is a WordPress / WooCommerce site. I only need to check the time to set the datepicker variable to 0 or 1. Nothing is going to the database.

Comment: So check on the server?  All checks should (also) be made on the server anyway, as it's extremely easy to bypass any checks you put client side.

Comment: The code is within a javascript block but I will still have the same issue, UTC vs. Local.

Comment: No: check on the server.  What technology are you using on the server to save your orders to the DB?  Check it there.

Comment: As @freedomn-m pointed out, you **must** check this on the server. If you want to check this on the Frontend to give the user some message or something, you can convert the user's Date to UTC, convert yours to UTC too, and then compare them. Still, as previously pointed out, users can meddle with that date on the Frontend. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours

Comment: What are you using in the back-end? nodejs or PHP?

Comment: This is a WordPress / WooCommerce site. I only need to check the time to set a datepicker variable. Nothing is going to the database. Code updated.

Comment: `currentTime.getUTCHours()`

Comment: @Lennholm Just to be clear, replace if (currentTime.getHours() >=9) with if (currentTime.getUTCHours() >=9) ?

Comment: currentTime.getUTCHours() did not work.